# Getting the value from simple JSP spring MVC page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I've created Spring MVC project via the MVC Template, but I can't get the value from the textinput. Can anybody advice me how to do that? Source of home.jsp with structure of the project can be seen at the screenshot bellow. Code of the AdminController class is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public class AdminController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/bar")
public String testAction(@RequestParam String fieldName) {
    // yourValue contain the value post from the html form
    return "yourview";
    }
}
```

[image: Here is the screenshot from the package explorer and source of home.jsp]

When I deploy the project, it starts on address `http://localhost:8080/test/` . Where to change `/test/` to something else? And after hitting the submit button, the browser forwards to `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar` and shows `HTTP status 404`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**404:**

Your form mapping is absolute

```
<form ... action="/foo/bar">
```

which is why it is hitting `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar` and you don't have an app deployed whose context path is `/foo` hence the 404.

To correct this use spring to add the context path for you:

```
<spring:url value="/foo/bar" var="form_url" />
<form ... action="${form_url}" method="POST">
```

**fieldName:**

You need to identify which request param to map to the testAction argument.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bar", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String testAction(@RequestParam(value="fieldName") String fieldName) {
  // yourValue contain the value post from the html form
  return "yourview";
}
```

**/test:**

Looks like you are using the Tomcat Server to run the app.  This is likely configured in pom.xml to start app using /${project.artifactId} (the default) where that your artifact id is "test".  (http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#path).  You can provide a different value by configuring the maven plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <path>WHATEVER</path>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the picture you have posted here. Your request mapping of controller is /bar and you form action is mentioned as /foo/bar. See if this is mistake. Provide request method to spring action method also.

Since you are accessing application using URL localhost:8080/foo/bar, I suggest some changes looking at it.

Remove RequestMapping tag from Controller. It should be :

```
@Controller    
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "bar", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String testAction(@RequestParam String fieldName) {
      // yourValue contain the value post from the html form
       return "yourview";
    }
}
```

And give form action name like action="bar".

Comment: thanks... redirecting to other page now works fine :) But how to print the text from <input name="fieldName" type="text" /> after redirecting to other page thanks to the hitting submit button?

Comment: Do you get that value in testAction method ? I guess if you are posting a form, you need to have those fields in a POJO.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, but I've hoped that there will be some better solution, like usage of ManagedBeans, that I know from JSF... Anyway :) thanks a lot :)